# How to forward Username and Password in SoapHeader to a Java WebService

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am consuming Java Web Service in VB.Net and I need to forward username, password in the Soap Header from client code.

Am not aware of this procedure. Can anyone let me know an example or sample code to forward the parameters from VB.Net client code.

Comment: Have you tried just using "Add Service Reference"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77hkfhh8.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whew6x7f.aspx

Comment: -1: first, please don't post answers that contain nothing but the links. If the links ever break, then your answer will be worthless. Second, don't ever post .NET 1.1 links unless the problem is specific to .NET 1.1.